# PHP - Assign a variable to if else statement

Tags: php

I haven't been able to find a solid answer to this. Is it possible to assign a variable to a if/else statement so I don't have to include the entire statement in some HTML.

For example, is this correct and if not what is the correct way?

```
$agency = if ($event == "Tornado Watch" || $event == "Severe Thunderstorm Watch") {
             echo "NWS Storm Prediction Center";
        } elseif ($event == "Hurricane Watch" || $event == "Tropical Storm Watch") {
             echo "NWS National Hurricane Center";
        } else {
             echo $wfo;
        }
```

Comment: Not that way but you can use a ternary operator or a switch case. What you have there will thrown an `unexpected if` notice.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: First off not sure why this was down voted so please explain. Second, what I am trying to achieve was stated in my post. I am trying to prevent from having to insert that entire statement inside a div tag. It is much cleaner to just insert a variable and keep the core logic within the core php.

Comment: 1. I didn't downvote. 2. Why can't you just use a function?

Comment: The answer from Rob is what you need, but also note that the text in your condition is too long. Event can be replaced by some smaller values. Ex: 1 for Tornado, 2 for Thunderstorm, etc. This way you don't risk making a typo in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is assign a value to $agency based on some logic and then echo the value of $agency.

```
<?php
$agency = $wfo;
if ($event == "Tornado Watch" || $event == "Severe Thunderstorm Watch")
{
    $agency = "NWS Storm Prediction Center";
}
elseif ($event == "Hurricane Watch" || $event == "Tropical Storm Watch")
{
    $agency = "NWS National Hurricane Center";
}

echo $agency;
```

[Edit] You may find it more maintainable to skip having all of your string comparisons blown out into control structures and create an associative array to map your events to agencies. There are a number of ways you could do this, here's a simple one:

```
<?php
$eventAgencyMap = [
    'Tornado Watch'             => 'NWS Storm Prediction Center',
    'Severe Thunderstorm Watch' => 'NWS Storm Prediction Center',
    'Hurricane Watch'           => 'NWS National Hurricane Center',
    'Tropical Storm Watch'      => 'NWS National Hurricane Center'
];

$agency = (array_key_exists($event, $eventAgencyMap)) ? $eventAgencyMap[$event] : $wfo;
```

Comment: Ah very nice, it's all in how you arrange the logic, that solution completely slipped me. PHP fooled me again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used Rob's solution as IMO it is a little more cleaner and less code. With that said I wanted to throw out this solution as well that worked for me too. Someone mentioned switch statement which I was thinking about too. So I tried it before I saw Rob's answer and this worked for me well. So it is an alternative way even though Rob's should be the chosen solution.

```
    $agency = '';

           switch($event)
{

              case 'Tornado Watch':
                    $agency = 'NWS Storm Prediction Center';
                              break;
              case 'Severe Thunderstorm Watch':
                    $agency = 'NWS Storm Prediction Center';
                              break;
              case 'Hurricane Watch':
                    $agency = 'NWS National Hurricane Center';
                              break;            
              case 'Tropical Storm Watch':
                    $agency = 'NWS National Hurricane Center';
                              break;
              case 'Flash Flood Watch':
                    $agency = $wfo;
                              break;

}
```

Comment: I'd say I prefer this way - although I would always recommend having a default in a switch statement in case you missed a case

Comment: You make a good and valid point. In my case though I am also using an array_filter so I already know those are the only case. Now that you mention it I guess I could use my last statement as the default.